# Geometry Nodes - Why Isn't My Mesh Boolean Working?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created two mesh objects.  I want the larger one (in Yellow) to cut the smaller one (in Red) using a Mesh Boolean node.  Why isn't it working?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/in6ke0y2z5gmo74s8w99y/Bool-Why.blend?rlkey=zmify5vrpeyurxqr4ecsexwwa&dl=0)

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

I'm really hoping someone can open this up and let me know what I'm missing.  I fear it might be a program glitch, and I don't know how to get around it.

When I recreate the exact same node tree (simplified) it works as expected:

[image]

But for some reason my node tree, which is slightly more complicated, is causing the bool to fail.

Comment: When you join the extruded mesh with the original you need to flip the original's faces and Merge the vertices by distance after Joining them. Here is a screenshot of which nodes you need to add (highlighted in light blue): https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZACv.png

Comment: Thank you @RumenBelev!  You've saved me so much headache.  It was the flipped face, that's all I needed to add.  Merge By Distance not necessary.  I didn't know that a normal could break a bool.  Do you want to post this as an answer to my question so I can mark it?

Comment: Hi, Glen. I think Merge by distance is important in more complicated situations. Just keep it in mind if Booleans do not work or you get double vertices (test your results by applying the modifier and examining the result mesh). As for posting it as an answer -  it is too simple to set up a step by step solution. If you find my comment useful you can press the small Up button next to them. Cheers!